# Non-static azure function not getting called

Tags: c#, azure, dependency-injection, azure-functions

Recently my team project decided to switch from static functions to dependency injection. We implemented it as shown in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection

However making function non-static I get the following error: "Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined."

https://i.stack.imgur.com/16ypU.jpg

Function:

```
    private readonly IUserService _userService;
    public UserFunctions(IUserService userService)
    {
         _userService = userService;
    }

    [FunctionName("GetUserById")]
    public IActionResult GetUserById(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "users")]
    HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
    {
        try
        {
            var userId = req.Query["userId"].ToString();

            if(userId == "")
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid query string");
            }

            var user = _userService.GetUserById(userId);
            if (user == null)
                return new NotFoundObjectResult("No user with such id found");
            user.IsPKSerialized = false;
            return new OkObjectResult(user);      
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            log.LogError(e,e.Message);
            return new StatusCodeResult(500);
        }
    }
```

Startup fragment:

```
public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
{
    public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
    }
}
```

I feel like the function itself is not getting called. When I put a breakpoint while debugging nothing happens.

Comment: Where is your constructor to initialize `IUserService`

Comment: I've updated the post with additional code

Comment: Do you see the error is the `func host` console ?

Comment: Yes, check imgur link above

Comment: @Alienown The status is `500`, and you return that in your catch. check logs to see what exception message you logged.

Comment: just wondering why did you make it nonstatic?